# $\int x2^{x+1} \, dx$

Tags: integration

What is $\int x2^{x+1} \, dx$ ?

I attempted integration by parts by substituting $u=x$ and $dv=2^{x+1} \, dx$, which got $du=dx$ and $v=\frac{2^{x+1}}{\ln(x+1)}$ but integrating $v$ was not easy enough.

Comment: If $dv=2^{x+1}\,dx$ then $v=\dfrac{2^{x+1}}{\ln 2}$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Your $v$ is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about integrating by parts. It would be easier if you expressed $2^{(x+1)}$ as $2e^{(\ln 2)x}$, so that the integral to evaluate becomes:
$$\int{x2^{x+1}}dx=2\int{xe^{(\ln 2)x}}dx$$
Setting $u=x$ and $dv=e^{(\ln 2)x}$ for integration by parts results in:-
$$2\int{xe^{(\ln 2)x}}dx=2\left[\frac{x}{\ln 2}e^{(\ln 2)x}-\frac{1}{\ln 2}\int e^{(\ln 2)x}dx\right]$$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: since $2^{x+1} = 2.2^x= 2e^{\ln(2)x}$, try integrating $xe^{ax}$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_0^a {x2^{x+1}}dx = \int_0^a {x e^{(x+1)\ln(2)}}dx = \left.\frac{1}{\ln(2)}x e^{(x+1)\ln(2)}\right|^a_0 - \int_0^a \frac{1}{\ln(2)}{e^{(x+1)\ln(2)}}dx = \frac{1}{\ln(2)}a e^{(a+1)\ln(2)} - \frac{1}{\ln(2)^2}(e^{(a+1)\ln(2)}-2)$$
that the second equality is from integration by part theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=x$ and $dv=2^{x+1}dx$

$\therefore du=dx$ and $v=\frac{2^{x+1}}{\ln2}$

$I=\frac{x2^{x+1}}{\ln2}-\frac{1}{\ln2}\int{2^{x+1}}dx\\=\frac{x2^{x+1}}{\ln2}-\frac{2^{x+1}}{(\ln2)^2}+C$